# Parsing a string input into a lambda function with multiple parameters

Tags: python, python-ast

How can I parse a string input into the proper form which could be used as  the first callable parameter of [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)?

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
x = np.arange(100)
y = 2*np.exp(-x)*3.14/2+1
```

The string is a math formula inputted by some users with no knowledge of Python.  The `parse` function take these formulas as input:

```python
f = parse('a*exp(-x)*b/c+d')
f1 = parse('k*x+b')
f2 = parse('k*sin(x*w)+b')
```

and parse / interpret them to  python lambda functions:

```python
f = lambda x,a,b,c,d: a*numpy.exp(-x)*b/c+d
f1 = lambda x,k,b: k*x+b
f2 = lambda x,k,w,b: k*sin(x*w)+b
```

so that `f` can be called by `curve_fit`

```python
p,pcov = curve_fit(f,x,y)
```

I've found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75434218/evaluate-a-mathematical-expression-with-a-call-to-functions-in-a-string-in-pytho) on Stack Overflow but there are no answers or comments.

Comment: Just use `input_str = input_str.replace('exp(', 'numpy.exp(')` in preprocessing.

Comment: @JonnyHenly The formulas are inputted by the user.  Didn't know what kind of formula they would use.  The only thing I know is that the input string is a legal math formula

Comment: Lots of inputs fall under *"legal math formula"*. You may want to impose, and thoroughly document, a definition of *acceptable math formula* for your program, otherwise you may be spending a long time writing a formula parser.

Comment: The original requirement is to mimic the MATLAB curve fitting toolkit （`cftool`） using python. Lots of formulas (linear, nonlinear, parametric, and nonparametric models) are included.

Comment: What you're looking for is doable, you just need to limit variables names to 1 character strings and parse the user input into an actual  `"lambda x, y, z: ..."` string before calling `eval`. I'll try to write an answer tonight if I have time.

Comment: Was posted as an issue for pyparsing here (https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/537), with basic solution added as a comment.

Comment: @PaulMcG  Thank you very much. The great  `pyparsing`  is what I need. It's a time-saver for me.

Answer (score 0):

- you can just use `eval` to achieve it with some extra input.
- input:

```
input a lambda: x,a,b,c,d:a*np.exp(-x)*b/c+d
```

- example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
x = np.arange(100)
y = 2*np.exp(-x)*3.14/2+1
fx = input("input a lambda: ")
f = eval("lambda "+fx)
p,pcov=curve_fit(f,x,y)
```

- If you really want to write the `parse()`, basically rewrite the python interpreter, which is overkill to this problem.

Comment: What the user would input is out of control of the program. Hardcoded is not suitable